# HTML / CSS Setting for Opera

Tags: html, css

```
body
{
 padding:0px;
 background:#2786f4;
 position:relative;
 margin:0;
 color:#818181;
 text-align:center;
} 

 <!--[if IE]>
                        <style>
                                #Right
                                {
                                    width:202px;
                                    background:#f1f1f1;
                                    padding:8px;
                                    position:absolute;
                                    top:130px;
                                    left:945px;
                                    float:right;
                                    text-align:left;
                                }
                                </style>
                        <![endif]-->

<div  id="Right"  >
             sadlf ljas dfjlsdjflsfjsl a;sldjf ;slfj
                </div>
```

---

I am facing a positioning problem while creating a HTML. It looks okay in all browsers except Opera.

How it will okay in Opera too ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? "Positioning" is very vague, you know. So, what do you expect, what does work in other browsers, what doesn't work in Opera exactly? Also I think you can exclude the conditional comments for IE since no other browser will use the code in there.

Comment: What *should* it look like and how *does* it look like in Opera? Not all of us have Opera installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a conditional comment that only works in IE. In IE, I see a light grey box on the right with the text in it.

All other browsers (Opera, Firefox Chrome) **don't** see the style for `#Right` and thus don't apply it. So they just show the grey text at the top.

It's not clear what you want to do, but if you want to hide that text completely from non-IE browsers, move the `<div>` inside the conditional comment, i.e. before `<![endif]-->`.